# class and recycler view error: can't instantiate class

Tags: android, service

I am struggling with this error:

> can't instantiate class com.dhruva.xxx.xxx.xxx$xxx; no empty constructor

I am developing one app where I used one service to upload multiple photo to server. I added service as inner class in activity.

Please see below, I get a `can't instantiate class : no empty constructor error` in LogCat when attempting to run my "SelectPhotos" class even though I clearly have an empty constructor there.

so I don't know how to remove that error. I tried from last week but I didn't get a solution. Now this is my last hope.

I hope I will get a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your import statement for Service so we can see what Service UploadService is extending, trying to reproduce.

Comment: Sir i added full code with import statement

Comment: Please check and give solution please

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
public class UploadService extends Service
```

with:

```
static public class UploadService extends Service
```

Comment: Let me try this one

Comment: I will try and let you know the result